# how to Spring @requestparam validate string is in list of strings

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am trying to replace hardcoded validation in below controller with @Valid annotation

```
@GetMapping(value = "/fruits")
public List<String> fruits(
@RequestParam(value = "fruitType", defaultValue = "") String fruitType) {

    final ImmutableList<String> fruitTypes = 
            ImmutableList.of("Citrus", "Seed Less", "Tropical");

    if (!fruitTypes.contains(fruitType)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Fruit type");
    }

    final ImmutableList<String> fruits = 
            ImmutableList.of("Apple", "Banana", "Orange");

    //filter fruits based on type, then return
    return fruits;
}
```

I know I can use @Pattern to check this using regex,

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/fruits")
    public List<String> fruits(@RequestParam(value = "fruitType", defaultValue = "")
                                    @Valid  @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp="Citrus|Seed Less|Tropical")
                                      String fruitType) {
//      final ImmutableList<String> fruitTypes = ImmutableList.of("Citrus", "Seed Less", "Tropical");
//      if (!fruitTypes.contains(fruitType)) {
//          throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Fruit type");
//      }
        final ImmutableList<String> fruits = ImmutableList.of("Apple", "Banana", "Orange");
        //filter fruits based on type, then return
        return fruits;
    }
```

But if the list of fruitType is not static
Is there any other spring way to do it ?

Comment: Write your own constraint annotation and associated validator that checks the value agains the dynamic list of values.

Answer (score 0):

As you are validating against custom list, there is no out of the box way to do this. However, to validate the types, you can define `FruitType` as `enum` and annotate it with `@RequestParam`, e.g.:

```
enum FruitType{
    Apple,
    Banana,
    Orange;
}

public List<String> fruits(
@RequestParam(value = "fruitType") FruitTypefruitType) {
//Implementation
```

Comment: "the list of `fruitType` is not static"

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum to validate the value and to throw the custom error you can use @RestControllerAdvice. Sample code is below.

```
enum FruitType {
        Apple, Banana, Orange;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/fruits")
    public List<String> fruits(@RequestParam(value = "fruitType") FruitType fruitType) {

        // You can put your business logic here.
        return fruits;
    }
```

//below is sample class for controller adviser..

```
 @RestControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
     @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<MpsErrorResponse> exceptionToDoHandler(HttpServletResponse response,
                                                                     MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex) throws IOException {

            return new ResponseEntity<>(new MpsErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), "Invalid Fruit type"),
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thought about it, but  As you see fruitType can have spaces that's why I Included "Seed Less" as one of the type. Also this is not static list , I have included it as a static list to de-clutter code